# Git: How to add a remote, merged in a sub folder of a master repository?

Tags: git, codeigniter, github

I've cloned the codeigniter repository https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter, which in particular creates the application and system folders.

The application folder has sub-folders, libraries and third-party, which are of interest right now.

I'd like to clone this repository : https://github.com/iamfiscus/Codeigniter-DOMPDF which has in its own root the libraries and third-party folders.

Is there a way to add a new remote to Codeigniter-DOMPDF in my codeigniter repository, which would copy the files and folders in the correct places?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add dompdf git://github.com/iamfiscus/Codeigniter-DOMPDF.git
git pull dompdf master
```

You create an additional remote with the first statement (naming it "dompdf").
Then, you pull the branch that you want (master?) from the dompdf repo into your branch.